# Wait for Other Method to complete updating List and then Executes Other Method to consume common property

Tags: c#, .net

I have two methods:

```
public List<int> MyData {get;set;}

public async Task MethodA(){
   // some logic here which process MyList
}

public async Task MethodB(){
   // This method takes time in execution and update MyData list
   MyData.Add(<Numeric value>);
}
```

MethodB() is called by a separate application asynchronously which adds data in MyData List (This is time taking process).

MethodA() which uses MyData List to give result which runs by separate application. Since MethodB() is still running and Not completely updated MyData List, **MethodA() sends incomplete list of MyData List to other application**.

How can I keep busy MethodA() to send data as soon as List is updated or something to send complete list to application?

Comment: MethodB() is called by a separate application asynchronously you say. And when that is done method A should be called. Why not call A at the end of B?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0) instance instead of a List? Then, have a Thread spin and dequeue items as they appear to run on **MethodA**.

Comment: Used it but this one is not working in my case as MethodB() runs independently while MethodA() run independently and has a common list that is updated by MethodB() which takes time to get completed.

Comment: Right, so do all the necessary work to generate the item(s) to enqueue on the ConcurrentQueue, then, dequeue from MethodA. This will prevent those issues.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the await keyword on MethodB and make sure it is called first then as soon as MethodB completes call MethodA to use the list.

```
public List<int> MyData {get;set;}

public async Task MethodA(){
   // some logic here which process MyList
}

public async Task MethodB(){
   // This method takes time in execution and update MyData list
   MyData.Add(<Numeric value>);
}

public void CallingMethod()
{
await MethodB();  //Wait for method to update list
MethodA(); //When MethodB completes process list
}
```

Comment: The problem is MethodB() will run first time and it updates the list while MethodA() executes without knowing about status of MethodB(). We can't control execution of MethodB();

Comment: It may just be over my head. Still learning as well. But would love to see the code if you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

So in the case where you don't have control in the method which Updates a list or some common variable where other methods are not bound to wait first method to get completed, we need to manually check if that process is completed if not then again first to check if it is done.

```
public List<int> MyData {get;set;}
// Variable to check
Private bool IsMethodBCompleted {get;set;}

public async Task MethodA(){
   // some logic here which process MyList
   // Return IsMethodBCompleted  as param to this method so that client can know if completed
}

public async Task MethodB(){
   // This method takes time in execution and update MyData list
   MyData.Add(<Numeric value>);
   
   // Mark the property true when done loading
   IsMethodBCompleted = true;
}
```

Client will access MethodA() and check if not completed then again call it.